# PHP Imagick Fatal Error on PNG file

Tags: php, imagick

I got script creating thumbnails , the problem got today that some images creating fatal error at this line:

```
$im = new imagick($filename);
```

Below is the error message -

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'corrupt image `imagename.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3789' in common.php:370
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 common.php(370): Imagick->__construct('...')

After some research I notice that it could be bug of imagick with some png files, this happens 1st time so its probably very rare

How to handle this error so it wont stop script ?

I thought about validating image format before but did not find anything working.

Comment: Publish png file which is dooing problem.

Comment: "How to handle this error so it wont stop script" -> catch the exception

Comment: Here is link to it https://filebin.net/xhsyg1t8tnc7l9rz/currupted.png?t=zl51wd2s , its opening fine in windows, no errors, nothing , a bit large

Answer (score 1):

> How to handle this error so it wont stop script ?

As pointed out in the comments, you need to handle the exception to allow the script to continue.

```php
try {
    $im = new Imagick($filename);
} catch (ImagickException $e) {
    $im = null;
    // .. handle error ..
}
if ($im) { // .. do work ..
```

> I thought about validating image format before but did not find anything working.

There's the [`Imagick::pingImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.pingimage.php) method to help identify meta-information about an image. This can be used to ensure the file matches what the application is expecting -- without decoding the image-data into memory.

However the image your working with seems to have bad chunk-data during the decoding sub-routines, so pinging the image wouldn't catch it. Corrupted images are common, and your solution should anticipate it with error handling.